# How salt concentration can effect the rate of corrosion and how redox reaction plays a role in that

Tags: reaction-mechanism

sub-questions:
What role do oxidation and reduction play in corrosion? Is this a complicated process?
Also, why does increase in salt concentration make it easier to rust?

Comment: IF you want "all the details" then read a few books about corrosion.

Answer (score 1):

To be short, the reaction is not between the iron and salt but between the iron and the oxygen from the air. The salt and the moisture (water) just opens the electrochemical pathway for this, when certain fragments of iron surface will have slightly different potentials (because of mechanical roughness, impurities, damaged coatings, etc.), thus creating a local electrochemical cell (a battery in a way).

The oxygen which is dissolved in water readily reduces on the cathode while the iron oxidizes on the anode and transfers into the salty moisture (the solution) as $\ce{Fe^2+}$ ions, which migrate to the cathode via solution and, together with the oxygen gas being reduced, form the rust. And $\ce{Fe^2+}$ also gets oxidized to $\ce{Fe^3+}$ a lot; the ferric oxide $\ce{Fe2O3}$ and the mixed oxide $\ce{Fe3O4}$ actually slow the corrosion process by forming a protective layer. Also, the overpotential of the oxygen plays a role (connected with the phase change, if I have not mistaken).

The chloride anions also are forming a soluble complex with $\ce{Fe^2+}$ which partially removes the $\ce{Fe^2+}$ ions from the oxidation process, hampering the formation of the ferric oxide protective layer. So the chloride ions have two roles: providing the better conductivity in the electrolyte which favours the electrochemical pathway of corrosion and the concurring reaction which slows the formation of the protective layer. See, e.g., Ahmad, Z. Concrete Corrosion. *Principles of Corrosion Engineering and Corrosion Control* **2006,** 609–646. [DOI: 10.1016/B978-075065924-6/50013-1](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-075065924-6/50013-1).